# Web Driver throws nullpointer exception while trying to find Element in my application

Tags: automated-testing

```
public class Loginpage {

public  WebDriver driver;


    By uname = By.xpath("//*[@id='UserName']");
    By nextbutton = By.id("btnNext");
    By passw = By.id("Password");
    By signinbtn = By.id("btnSubmit");


    public Loginpage(WebDriver driver){
        driver = this.driver;

    }

    public void setUserName(String uid ,String pass){

        driver.findElement(uname).sendKeys(uid);
        driver.findElement(nextbutton).click();
        driver.findElement(passw).sendKeys(pass);
        driver.findElement(signinbtn).click();

}
}
```

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2 Starting ChromeDriver
>   2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb) on port 23334 Only local connections are allowed. Sep 20, 2018 4:24:48 PM
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO:
>   Detected dialect: OSS java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   Testrun.Loginpage.setUserName(Loginpage.java:24)  at
>   Testrun.Logintopage.validlogin(Logintopage.java:22)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)   at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

```
@Test
  public void validlogin() throws InterruptedException {

      try{
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
          //this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
      driver.get("https://qa.reventics.com/REVCDIUTROP_PROD/");
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      Loginpage login = new Loginpage(driver);

     login.setUserName("George", "Reventics@1");

      }catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: it may be because of driver is becoming null.it is not issue with finding element

Comment: Welcome to SQA. Identifying `NullPointerException`s is a common problem. Here's how to investigate it yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871825/a-good-way-to-debug-nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 3):

Your assignment doesn't look proper (there might be other problems which I did not look at). Instead of:

```
driver = this.driver;
```

You need to use

```
this.driver = driver
```

Answer (score 0):

May be find elements is taking time to the element path better use ***implicit or explicit wait*** condition so it will wait till it will the path of the element you have given.

For me it worked in one senior